# How to tile an image from center using UIColor patternImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicolor

I have a method for repeating or tiling an image across a view using `UIColor` `patternImage`:

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:imageName))`

The default behaviour of `UIColor` `patternImage` is to start the pattern from the top left, the result shown in Image 1.

**Question:**

**How can I get `UIColor` `patternImage` to start always from the very center of a view, patterning outwards to give the result shown in Image 2?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works. It is a generalised method that applies more broadly, adapting dynamically to both pattern images and views of different heights and widths. It gives the desired result in the question and is tested on different iOS simulators.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)
view.bounds.origin.x = (UIImage(named: "imageName")!.size.width/2) - (view.bounds.size.width/2)
view.bounds.origin.y = (UIImage(named: "imageName")!.size.height/2) - (view.bounds.size.height/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image size is 50*50 then you can do something like this,

```
 myView = UIVIew(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.frame.size.width/2)-25, y: (self.view.frame.size.height/2)-25, width: 50, height: 50))
```

So this view(imageview in yourcase may be) will be place at exact middle of view. Like wise you can arrange other view by adding or substracting view's `width` and `height` to center view's `x` and `y` origin. Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: This didn't work, but it made me revisit my maths and create a generalised method that could apply more broadly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created reusable class `PatternView`, reusing idea of [@user4806509](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4806509/user4806509). It's really drop-in component for showing patterns. Also, `patternImage` can be set via `Interface Builder`

```
class PatternView: UIView {
   @IBInspectable var patternImage: UIImage?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

       self.setupBackgroundColor()
   }

    private func setupBackgroundColor() {
       guard let patternImage = self.patternImage else {
          return
       }

       self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: patternImage)
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()

      self.centerPattern()
   }

   private func centerPattern() {
       guard let patternSize = self.patternImage?.size,
             patternSize.width > 0, patternSize.height > 0 else {
          return
       }

      let x = -self.bounds.width.remainder(dividingBy: patternSize.width)/2
      let y = -self.bounds.height.remainder(dividingBy: patternSize.height)/2
      self.bounds.origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
  }}
```